# Docker not building image as expected with EC2 ECR

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, dockerfile, amazon-ecr

I'm using Docker for the first time and am running into an issue where I think my main problem is I'm not sure of the *source* of the issue. I'm running an EC2 instance on AWS, which is properly configured, etc. to host a site.

If I have an update to my git repo, I can manually ssh into the git repo, run

```
git pull
sudo docker-compose down -v --remove-orphans
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d --build
```

and this works like a charm.

However, I've been working on a pipeline with GitHub actions, and I'm pretty much containerizing the code that was pushed into a Docker image, pushing this to an ECR private repo, and then sshing into the EC2 instance, pulling the new image I just pushed, decomposing the old one, and (well, herein lies the issue), restarting with the new image.

I've debugged a bunch and I am fairly certain that the image pushed to my ECR private repo is correct, and I'm certain that it is on the EC2 instance/I have access to it.

The relevant portion of my Dockerfile is:

```yaml
- name: Permission for ecr 
        run: ssh staging 'aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | sudo docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${{ secrets.AWS_ECR_REGISTRY }}'
      - name: Pull new image
        run: ssh staging 'sudo docker pull ${{ secrets.AWS_ECR_REGISTRY }}/my-repo:latest'
      - name: Stop running container
        run: ssh staging 'cd vms; sudo docker-compose down -v --remove-orphans'
      - name: Start new container
        run: ssh staging 'cd vms; sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d --build'
```

I think the issue might actually lie in my Dockerfile itself:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/ #line I'm concerned about
EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

since what this does is copy everything *in the current directory* to the code volume. I think this might be a problem because, sure maybe I pull and push the docker image correctly to the server, but when I actually run `sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d --build` my best guess is that everything in the current directory is containerized and started, but I'd like *my new image that I pushed* to be started up.

Edit: here's the docker-compose.prod.yml file:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: ..
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn vms.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ..:/code
    expose:
      - 8000
  nginx:
    build: ../nginx
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on: 
      - web
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you add the `docker-compose-prod.yml` file?

Comment: just added it, sorry about that!

Comment: No worries. I added the answer. Maybe it might not work for you out of the box. But you can get the idea what went wrong.

Comment: 2nd code block is labelled as a dockerfile, but it clearly isn't -- can you fix that, please? I don't know what I'm looking at there.

Comment: Hi, Yeah update on this, I was able to fix it! It ended up being that, like the answer below, I had to use an image instead, and I also removed the volumes: ../:code from the docker-compose.prod.yml file; also, I replaced `ENTRYPOINT python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python manage.py run` with `CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]` in the Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you’re trying to build the docker image again. Since you push it to ECR, instead of building it you can simply use the built image and run it out of the box.

Use this `docker-compose.prod.yml` file instead:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    image: <path-to-your-docker-image-in-ecr>
    command: gunicorn vms.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
  nginx:
    image: <nginx-image-you-need>
    ports:
      - 1334:80
    depends_on: 
      - web
```

Note that I have removed the `build` step in both your apps and replaced them with `image`. You have to fill the proper values in there.

And replace the build command using the following:

```sh
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
```

Hope this helps you. Cheers !!!

Comment: Ah okay thank you so much this makes a lot of sense! One quick question for the <path-to-your-docker-image-in-ecr>, I currently have a bunch of images, where the one I want to build from has the "latest" tag. I tried: `image: my-repo:latest` but this didn't seem to work -- is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Do you have the image with the tag “latest”? You need to push your image to ECR with the same tag you use in the docker-compose file. Try to use docker pull command in your local machine and check whether you can pull that image with the same tag? I’m guessing you did not tag it.

Comment: Ah yes okay I was able to figure this out, but alas it seems like I'm still having the same problem as before! Now, I do build the new image, so, for example, if I have an image with id: 90d1263c6fb8, and I specify `build: image: 66f04118ce2e`, this successfully builds, but, at the end of the day, whatever is shown on the website is still just coming straight out of code in the current directory, and seems unrelated to the image at all.

Comment: update: I may have found the source of the problem, I think it lies in the Dockerfile itself -- might post a followup question later but either way this answer makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Nice, for a person who used docker for the first time, you're doing great. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Update for anyone else who has a similar issue, I ended up resolving this by replacing the "ENTRYPOINT" line in my dockerfile with this line: `CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]`
and I also  removed:

```
volumes:
  - ..:/code
```

from the docker-compose file + changed to use an image, like the accepted answer mentions. Played around with a lot of things (as is typical in dev ops, I guess) so not sure *exactly* what was causing the issues but my final docker compose file ended up looking like this:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    image: <aws-path>/simple-django:latest
    command: gunicorn vms.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    expose:
      - 8000
  nginx:
    build: ../nginx
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on: 
      - web
```

hope this helps someone in the future!